# DownloadManager: notify when a download is finished

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I've wrote a code to use a `DownloadManager` in order to download some files. Now I want to do the following:

1. Notify my activity when a download is finished (and which download is finished)
2. Receive periodical information about specific file's download progress (like happens in the play store, where the download progress is shown inside `DownloadManager` notification bar and inside google play current page)

Answer (score 9):

To receive a notification when the download is completed, register a Receiver to receive an `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast. It will include an `EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID` extra that contains the 
reference ID of the download that has completed.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long reference = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (myDownloadReference == reference) {
            // Do something with downloaded file.
       }
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```